# Custom WP Block using Inner Blocks crashes editor, doesn't save content

Tags: block-editor

I've finally gotten around to building a custom Gutenberg/WP Block for a project and it's basically kicking my ass.  Working with React, Node, WebPack, Gulp is all new enough to me so there's a learning curve I have to deal with but the incomplete and inaccurate documentation from WP is making things substantially worse.  *(Their documentation still says to use `wp.editor` but reading through tickets in GitHub I learned that was deprecated and should instead be `wp.blockEditor`, as an example.)*

As of right now, I've got a custom block loading in my editor that is supposed to accept `InnerBlocks`.  The process of adding a block and adding blocks into it works just fine.

Where things go wrong is after the page/post is 'Updated'.  I get a bunch of different errors and a white screen of death.  One of the errors that sometimes comes up is a React Minification #321 error.  But there's others as well and not always the same errors.

Here is the code used to register my block:

```
const { __, setLocaleData } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor; //was wp.editor

const blockStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#777',
    color: '#FFF',
    padding: '24px 2.5% 24px 2.5%',
};

registerBlockType( 'custom-layout-blocks/custom-stripe-rows', {
    title: __( 'Striped Block Row', 'custom-layout-blocks' ),
    icon: 'tide',
    category: 'layout',
    styles: [
        {
            name: 'magenta-stripes',
            label: 'Magenta',
            isDefault: true
        },
        {
            name: 'teal-stripes',
            label: 'Teal'
        },
        {
            name: 'evergreen-stripes',
            label: 'Evergreen'
        },
    ],
    edit() {
        return (
            <div style={blockStyle}><InnerBlocks /></div>
        );
    },
    save() {
        return (
            <div style={blockStyle}><InnerBlocks /></div>
        );
    }
} );
```

Now here's the relevant PHP:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
    function custom_layoutblocks_load_textdomain() {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'custom-layout-blocks', false, basename( __DIR__ ) . '/languages' );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_layoutblocks_load_textdomain' );

    function custom_layoutblocks_register_block() {
        if( !function_exists( 'register_block_type' ) ) {
            // Gutenberg is not active.
            return;
        }
        wp_register_script(
            'custom-striped-rows',
            plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
            array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-block-editor' ),
            filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.js' )
        );
        wp_register_style(
            'custom-editor',
            plugins_url( 'css/custom-editor.css', __FILE__ ),
            array( 'wp-edit-blocks' ),
            filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'css/custom-editor.css' )
        );
        wp_register_style(
            'custom-style',
            plugins_url( 'css/custom-front.css', __FILE__ ),
            array(),
            filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'css/custom-front.css' )
        );
        wp_style_add_data( 'custom-style', 'path', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/css/custom-front.css' );
        register_block_type( 'custom-layout-blocks/custom-stripe-rows', array(
            'api_version'   => 2,
            'style'         => 'custom-style',
            'editor_style'  => 'custom-editor',
            'editor_script' => 'custom-striped-rows',
        ) );
        if( function_exists( 'wp_set_script_translations' ) ) {
            wp_set_script_translations( 'custom-striped-rows', 'custom-layout-blocks' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_layoutblocks_register_block' );
```

** I've changed all the prefixes to 'custom' to keep this generic and applicable to anyone else that comes across this.

WebPack is tracking changes and the files are all being updated, I can run the plugin in my dev environment and on a staging site.  Where it all falls apart is when I update an entry with my custom block in it. Everything seems to go haywire from there and the content doesn't show up in the front end, not even in the source.

**Update:**

Here's the error I get on the edit screen after I've added the block and added a paragraph block to it.

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '(e.target.getAttribute("data-block")?e.target:e.target.closest("[data-block]")).getAttribute')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation of the issues in your code:

1. The main one which causes the block editor to crash, is because you used `InnerBlocks` in the `save` function. You should instead *use `InnerBlocks.Content`*.

   See [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/) and [this](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/cdbab7fff0d285787a565fe0e23b620b28ab1922/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks) for more details on `InnerBlocks` usage, accepted props, etc.
2. As for the `getAttribute` error, it's because you did not use [`useBlockProps`](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/18/block-api-version-2/) in the `edit` function (which should also be used in the `save` function).

   And why should you use `useBlockProps`, is because when you registered the block type in JavaScript (using `registerBlockType()`), you didn't set the `apiVersion` property, hence Gutenberg uses the `api_version` value (which is **2**) you set via PHP (using [`register_block_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/)), and when using the block API version 2, `useBlockProps` should be used, so that the block is properly wrapped, centered and "clickable".

So to fix the issues:

- At the top in your script, replace the `const { InnerBlocks } = wp.blockEditor;` with:

  ```js
  const { InnerBlocks, useBlockProps } = wp.blockEditor;
  ```
- Use `useBlockProps()` in the `edit` function, and `useBlockProps.save()` and `InnerBlocks.Content` in the `save` function:

  ```js
  edit() {
      const blockProps = useBlockProps( { style: blockStyle } );

      return (
          <div { ...blockProps }><InnerBlocks /></div>
      );
  },
  save() {
      const blockProps = useBlockProps.save( { style: blockStyle } );

      return (
          <div { ...blockProps }><InnerBlocks.Content /></div>
      );
  }
  ```

### Additional Notes

- Are you already using the [`@wordpress/scripts` package](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/) to build your scripts (see [JavaScript build setup in the block editor handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/javascript/js-build-setup/))?

  Because if you are, you wouldn't need to manually specify the dependencies for your script, which is `array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-block-editor' )` in the question.

  However, you will need to use the `import` statement and not `const` when loading the dependencies in your script. So for example:

  ```js
  // Instead of using "const":
  const { InnerBlocks, useBlockProps } = wp.blockEditor;

  // Use "import":
  import { InnerBlocks, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
  ```

### In response to your comment...

> if I replace `array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-block-editor' )` with just `array()` or any other combination,
> excluding any of them or all of them, I still get an error

The following [excerpt](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/javascript/js-build-setup/#dependency-management) might help:

> Here is how to use this asset file to automatically set the dependency
> list for enqueuing the script. This prevents having to manually update
> the dependencies, it will be created based on the package **import**s
> used within your block.
>
> ```
> $asset_file = include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php');
>
> wp_register_script(
>   'myguten-block',
>   plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
>   $asset_file['dependencies'],
>   $asset_file['version']
> );
> ```

Comment: Thanks Sally CJ, I'm going to apply all of this now.  The frustrating thing is that I had all of it set up very similar to what you've provided but when it didn't work I started to strip stuff out and simplify things as you do when you debug right... ...but I was using `import` with `wp.editor` that I picked up from the documentation and it was only hours later that I found that `wp.editor` had been deprecated. I didn't realize all the other aspects were still required to get it to even work at it's most basic.  Thank you again.

Comment: I can't be the only one that posts a question on here and then shuts down for the day thinking "I really hope Sally CJ comes across my question." LOL!
Well it worked, so thank you.
The only thing is that I am using `@wordpress/scripts` which I added using `npm --save-dev --save-exact @wordpress/scripts` when I started the project, however if I replace `array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-block-editor' )` with just `array()` or any other combination, excluding any of them or all of them, I still get an error.  So unless there's an issue I guess I can leave it.

Comment: I guess the docs team did not have enough time to update all the docs... (which is why I don't rely completely on the docs and normally I would look at the relevant source code), or it's also possible they missed/forgot certain info/changes, or maybe their docs system automatically reverted/ignored their edits. :) And well, I'm happy that you had such a ("comes across") thought, LOL! Anyway, I don't know about that error in your previous comment, but the excerpt in my revised/reworded answer might help?

Comment: I'll look to implement that as well, thanks Sally CJ. I have to focus on the front end design of the rendered blocks first because they're super intricate and I've got people waiting to review.